# Accessing data frames from a set of strings in R

Tags: r

I have a set of strings

```
a = c("b1","b5","b7")
```

I have a list `abc` that has data frames `b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7`
when I try

```
for(i in a) {
  cde$i = abc$as.name(i)
}
```

I get an error because `abc$as.name(i)` is incorrect.
My question is How can I tell R to look at abc$"b1" as abc$b1

Comment: I don't know what `cde` is, but how about `cde[a] <- abc[a]`

Answer (score 1):

To get an element of a list by the value of an other variable, use `[[x]]` not anything involving `$` signs.

```
LIST = list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
a = "b"
LIST$a # gets 1, always the literal value after the dollar
LIST[[a]] # gets 2, evaluates its argument, results in string "b"  
LIST[["a"]] # gets 1, same as LIST$a, argument evaluates to a string.
```